# Create a Python Function in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a python function that I want to call in Excel. However I'm getting #VALUE errors, I think it's to do with passing an excel range to a python list.

Python function requires 2 inputs with 4 optional, the first input is a string with the second being a list of list of strings [rows[columns]], a score is then produced for the string against each row in the list. Finally outputting a dataframe:

```
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import feature_extraction, metrics
from typing import List, Any


class PythonObjectLibrary:
    _reg_clsid_ = pythoncom.CreateGuid()
    _reg_clsctx_ = pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    _reg_progid_ = "Python.ObjectLibrary"
    _reg_desc_ = "This is our Python object library."
    _public_methods_ = ['nlp_vlookup']

    def nlp_vlookup(value: str,
                    table: List[List[Any]],
                    col_index: int = None,
                    include_score: bool = False,
                    all_matches: bool = False,
                    threshold: float = 0.5) -> pd.DataFrame:

        words = [str(x[0]) for x in table]
        vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()
        vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform([value]+words).toarray()
        cosine_sim = metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(list(vectors))
        scores = cosine_sim[0][1:]
        scores_df = pd.DataFrame({"score": scores}, index=words)
        table_df = pd.DataFrame(table, index=words)
        df = table_df.join(scores_df)
        df = df[df["score"] >= threshold]

        if not len(df.index):
            raise ValueError("No matches found")
        df = df.sort_values(by="score", ascending=False)
        if not all_matches:
            df = df.head(1)
        columns = table_df.columns.to_list() if col_index is None else [col_index-1]
        if include_score:
            columns = ["score"] + columns
        df = df.reindex(columns=columns)

        return df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonObjectLibrary)

    # test function:
    # search_list = [['Capital bank'], ['The Little Bank'], ['The Big Bank']]
    # match = PythonObjectLibrary.nlp_vlookup("The Capital Bank", search_list, include_score=True, all_matches=True, threshold=0.5)
    # print(match)
```

Excel Function to map the python function:

```
Function nlp_vlookup(value As String, table As Range, col_index As Integer, include_score As Boolean, all_matches As Boolean, threshold As Double)
    nlp_vlookup = VBA.CreateObject("PythonObjectLibrary").nlp_vlookup(value, table, col_index, include_score, all_matches, threshold)
End Function
```

Comment: An Excel Range is an object peculiar to Excel. I think you are over-optimistic that Python can interpret the parameter as a Range, though I could be wrong. An easier way to pass the parameter as a Variant array (as this is a basic COM datatype). Put another couple of lines in the VBA: Dim vTable as Variant / vTable = table. Then call the Object function using vTable as the parameter rather than table. Also I am concerned over the CreateGuid() call ... that seems to create a new Guid everytime you run the Python code: usually you create one and hard-code it.

Comment: I'm still getting the same #VALUE error using variant rather then range. Also the python script is intended to be called once to enable the new function, then it's just excel.

Comment: I tried it out, and put my findings in the answer. (1) you need to pass a Variant array for 'table' (2) I dont think the COM wrapper understands DataFrames so you have to extract it  as a list array, (3) you need to do some work in VBA to convert the return 0-based array to a 1-based array so that Excel can display it in the sheet, and finally (4) using a global object to hold the VBA object rather than create a new one each time (which will speed things up on repeated calls).

Answer (score 0):

EDITED after @norie's comment, as it seems the zero-based array thing is a red herring.

I used this test Object (note the hard-coded UUID). It has a simple doubleArray() method that receives a Variant Array of numbers from Excel, doubles them, and returns an array. I have created a dummy DataFrame to test the extraction to a list. Apologies if the Python is inelegant ... I am only a beginner!

```
import pythoncom as pc
import win32com.client as cl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from win32com.client import Dispatch

class PythonComTestObject:
    _reg_clsid_ = '{BB58C07E-B9AD-4BC7-BB8C-01D2FF8FD4E9}' #replace this
    _reg_clsctx_ = pc.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
    _reg_progid_ = "PythonComTestObject.Library"
    _reg_desc_ = "A library for doubling things."

    # a list of strings that indicate the public methods for the object. If they aren't listed they are considered private.
    _public_methods_ = ['doubleArray']


    # double every value in array and return
    def doubleArray(self, vArray):     
        #the VARIANT array comes gets converted to an [[]] array
        nRows = len(vArray)
        nCols = len(vArray[0])
        
        headers = [ 'Col{0:}'.format(n) for n in range(1,nCols+1)]

        retDF = pd.DataFrame(np.array(vArray) * 2,columns=headers)

        return [retDF.columns.values.tolist()] + retDF.values.tolist()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import win32com.server.register
    
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(PythonComTestObject)
```

Then this is my VBA in Excel. I realize it is a bit more than the original. The conversion from a zero-based to a 1-based array could be put into a utility function. Note I've added a global object for my Python library, so that it gets created once and re-used. This makes subsequent function calls more rapid as you don't have to do the hard work of creating the object again.

```
Option Explicit

Dim g_PythonObj As Object

Public Function pythonDouble(rng As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo comerror
    
    'Initialize the global object
    If g_PythonObj Is Nothing Then
        Set g_PythonObj = CreateObject("PythonComTestObject.Library")
    End If
       
    'Convert the rng parameter to a variant array
    Dim vIn As Variant
    vIn = rng
    
    'Call the Python function
    pythonDouble = g_PythonObj.doubleArray(vIn)
    
    Exit Function
    
    'Catch any errors here
comerror:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    pythonDouble = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function

'A test subroutine for debugging
Sub testPython()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("Input") 'A range on my test sheet
    
    Dim vIn As Variant
    vIn = rng
    
    Dim vRes As Variant
    vRes = pythonDouble(vIn)
End Sub
```

This is the spreadsheet result:
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert from a 0-based index in Excel.  I removed the section of the code that does that and it worked. Mind you, it might be an idea to manipulate the result to remove 'Col1'.

Comment: @norie ... Thanks, You're right ... I was just trying different things (not quite at random, but close) and it worked. I didn't go back to check. The 'Col1' is just there as the OP was trying to return a DataFrame with headers, so I wanted a similar example.

Comment: I see where 'Col1' is coming from now.

Comment: This is actually quite cool. But could I humbly suggest that you use [xloil](https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/xlOil_Python/index.html) instead which takes care of all the registration, runs much faster and means you don't need to write VBA to invoke your python function